# Piecewise function plot with solution from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have these differential equations and I wanted to solve its solutions then plug it into an expression for temperature (which I have listed in the plot below), but the expression for temperature is a piece-wise function one for $t<t_b$ and the other is $t>t_b$.

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18;
m = 1.8*10^13;
Rm = (1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18);
v = 13.2 Mp;
Rv = 13.2;
\[Lambda] = 10^-13;
Tb = 10 (m/Mp)^4;
tf = 10^7; 
sol = NDSolve[{dy'[t] + 3 H[t] (1 + 10) dy[t] + \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - Rv^2) y[t] == 0, H[t] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + 0.25 \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - Rv^2)^2 + \[Rho][t])/3], \[Rho]'[t] + 4 H[t] \[Rho][t] == 3 H[t] 10 dy[t]^2, y'[t] == dy[t], y[0] == -30, dy[0] == 9*10^-6, \[Rho][0] == Rm^4}, {y, dy, H, \[Rho]}, {t, 0, tfin},MaxStepFraction -> 0.001, MaxSteps -> 5*10^7]
ysol = y[10^7] /. sol;
ypsol = dy[10^7] /. sol;
Hsol = H[10^7] /. sol
\[Rho][10^7] /. sol;
tb = ((3 Hsol (1 + 10))/(2 \[Lambda] Rv^2)) (Log[(40 Pi^2 Hsol^2 (1 + 10)^2)/(\[Lambda]^2 Rv^6 10)])
Plot[Piecewise[{{Tb Exp[Hsol (x - tb)],x < tb}, {Tb Exp[(\[Lambda] Rv^2 (x-tb))/(6 Hsol (1 + 10))], x > tb}}], {x, 0, 10^7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It gave me an error that tb is not a machine sized number, etc. Can anyone help me with this situation? Also, I'm fairly new with mathematica so I've got few more problems, does my code look correct? For example, I substituted "sol" to a function of x, but every quantity needs to be evaluated at some t, so I'm not sure. Just a note, the number 10 you see is something that I can change later so I just left it like that, example (1+10), I did not add it so that it is easier to change later.

Basically, I need to plot $T$ vs. $t$

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:
Suppose I have these codes, can anyone help me determine the proper $tf$ and $y[0]$ to get a plot like below, note that in my code $T = \frac{3 \rho[t]}{10 \pi^2}$ where $T$ is the temperature. Also, dy[0]=b shouldn't be too sensitive, $10^{-6}$ would be ok, it is just $y[0]$ and $tf$ that I somehow have some difficulties, although $0 \lt y[0] \lt 50$ (maybe it can go beyond 50 but 500 is too much I think). For some combination of $y[0]$ and $tf$, I'm getting an error saying ""For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions". I'm not sure how to determine the correct combination to get the plot, it's not necessary to get the exact same plot, but $T$ should somehow cut the line $H$ and go below it, like a slanted V.

[image]

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18;
m = 1.8*10^13;
Rm = (1.8*10^13 )/(2.4353*10^18);
\[Sigma] = 2.24*10^19;
\[Sigma]m = (2.24*10^19)/(2.4353*10^18);
\[Lambda] = ((1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18))^4;
tf = 10^9;
sol[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{dy'[t] + 303 H[t] dy[t] + 4 \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - \[Sigma]m^2) y[t] == 0, H[t] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - \[Sigma]m^2)^2 + \[Rho][t])/3], \[Rho]'[t] + 4 H[t] \[Rho][t] == 300 H[t] dy[t]^2, y'[t] == dy[t], y[0] == -a, dy[0] == b, \[Rho][0] == Rm^4}, {y, dy, H, \[Rho]}, {t, 0, tf}]
sol[1, 1/100000]
Manipulate[Plot[{Evaluate[H[t] /. First@sol[a, b]], Evaluate[(3 \[Rho][t]/10 Pi^2)^(1/4) /. First@sol[a, b]]}, {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> Automatic], {{a, 1}, 0, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1/100000}, 0, 0.00009, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

---

I have resolved the previous problem but suppose I wanted to plot $H$ and $T = (3\rho(t)/10 \pi^2)^{1/4}$ vs. $N$. I have written the code below but when I plot them it just shows the "$N$" axis, no axis for $H$ and $T$. What seems to be wrong in the code? I tried figuring out if I have some syntax error etc. but so far, I don't see anything wrong.

```
Mp = 2.4353 10^18; 
m = 1.8 10^15; 
Rm = (1.8 10^15 )/(2.4353 10^13); 
\[Sigma] = 2.24 10^19; 
R\[Sigma] = (2.24 10^19)/(2.4353 10^18); 
\[Lambda] = ((1.8 10^15)/(2.4353 10^18))^4; 
tf = 10^8; 
H[t_] = Sqrt[1/3 (0.5 y'[t]^2 + \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - R\[Sigma]^2)^2 + \[Rho][t])]; 

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[Rationalize[{y''[t] + 3 (1 + 0.5) H[t] y'[t] + 4 \[Lambda] (y[t]^2 - R\[Sigma]^2) y[t] == 0, \[Rho]'[t] + 4 H[t] \[Rho][t] == 1.5 H[t] y'[t]^2, D[Nx[t], t] == H[t], y[0] == -a, y'[0] == b, \[Rho][0] == Rm^4, Nx[0] == 0}, 0], {y, \[Rho], Nx}, {t, 0, tf}, {a, b}, AccuracyGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity] 

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{Nx[t], ((3 \[Rho][t])/(10 \[Pi]^2))^(1/4)}, {Nx[t], H[t]}} /. Thread[{y, \[Rho], Nx} -> sol[a, b]]], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> Automatic], {{a, 1}, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1/100000}, 0, 0.00009, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: The value for tfin seems to be missing and Hsol "seems funny"

Comment: @Bill I have edited my post, another problem is that I don't know how to determine the proper time $tf$ to calculate the differential equation, I'm just guessing, maybe $10^7$, and the proper initial conditions for the $dy[0]=10^{-6}$ is ok but for $y[0]$ I'm not sure. I should get a plot of $T$ vs $t$ such that the plot looks like a slanted "V", the function for t<tb should die but will be connected by the function for t>tb which should be increasing, but as I know the duration for the function t>tb takes longer to increase therefore the whole plot should be slanted.

Comment: Still, `tfin` is missing, you only have a `tf` defined in your code, if you modify `tfin` in `NDSolve` to `tf`, and all the `/.sol` to `/.sol[[1]]` (please think about why `{2} > 1` doesn't "work") then everything works well, the resulting graph isn't interesting though, clearly something is wrong with `tb`  or `tf`. (`tf` is much smaller than `tb`! )

Comment: @mathemania To have an output not just an empty plot, do this with `tb=Flatten[....][[1]]`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for that info. Is there a way to better determine the proper tf, I mean in general? Or is it just a guessing game?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it can be determined by no one except you, because `tb` and `tf` are parameters determined by the model behind the code, which you don't explain in your post.

Comment: @xzczd I have added an additional/related question, I have also added an example plot that I want to achieve but I'm not getting it and sometimes as I vary the initial conditions and tf I get an error which I stated above, maybe you can get a hindsight on what I stated above.

Answer (score 3):

Not a answer, but too long for a comment.

Well, as said above, I'm afraid it's hard to determine `a` and `b` just from a coding perspective. Put even more bluntly, currently we don't even know whether your modeling is correct or not. Anyway, your coding can be improved, here are some suggestions:

1. `NDSolve` is able to handle high-order derivative without any difficulty, there's no need to rewrite `y''[t]` to `dy'[t]`, and as far as I can tell, rewriting `y'[t]` as `dy[t]` won't make `NDSolve` work any better.
2. On the other hand, eliminating `H[t]` from the equation set will improve the performance of `NDSolve`, because there's no derivative for `H[t]` in the equation set, `NDSolve` will treat the equations as a DAE system. (Indeed, in some cases `NDSolve` will transform the DAE system to an ODE system, but not always, and the warning about `IDA` you encountered is exactly an evidence for the triggering of DAE solver, just search `IDA` in the document. ) The DAE solver of `NDSolve` is weaker compared to the ODE solver, so it's good to take the expression of `H[t]` out of `NDSolve`.
3. You can make use of `ParametricNDSolveValue` since `a` and `b` is under-determined.
4. Since the parameters are extreme, we need to raise the `WorkingPrecision` of `NDSolve`. Also, we need to use `Rationalize` to raise the precision of the parameters because you've used `MachinePrecision` numbers. (Actually in this case we just need to raise `AccuracyGoal` to e.g. `AccuracyGoal -> 16`, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138634/1871) for more information. Given [`AccuracyGoal` is a subtle option](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871), I'll stick to `WorkingPrecision` in the rest part of this post. )
5. The graph you posted is a logarithmic graph, so we can use `LogPlot`.
6. The position of `Evaluate` is wrong, it should be outside of the first argument of `Plot`, or it won't "break through" the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`.
7. With all due respect, you should put a bit more effort into learning the core language of *Mathematica*.

The following is an improved version of the code:

```
Mp = 2.4353 10^18;
m = 1.8 10^13;
Rm = (1.8 10^13)/(2.4353 10^18);
σ = 2.24 10^19;
σm = (2.24 10^19)/(2.4353 10^18);
λ = ((1.8 10^13)/(2.4353 10^18))^4;
tf = 10^9;
H[t_] = Sqrt[1/3 (0.5 y'[t]^2 + λ (y[t]^2 - σm^2)^2 + ρ[t])]
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  Rationalize[{y''[t] + 303 H[t] y'[t] + 4 λ (y[t]^2 - σm^2) y[t] == 0, 
    ρ'[t] + 4 H[t] ρ[t] == 300 H[t] y'[t]^2, y[0] == -a, 
    y'[0] == b, ρ[0] == Rm^4}, 0], {y, ρ}, {t, 0, tf}, {a, b}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32]

LogPlot[{H[t], (3/10 ρ[t] π^2)^(1/4)} /. 
   Thread[{y, ρ} -> sol[200, 10^-1]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, tf/100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As we can see, under the parameters chosen above, though not crossing curve of $H$, the curve of $T$ bends. Though the goal isn't achieved, it's a small step forward, I think.

Comment: If the Evaluate is outside then what is it evaluating? Why is there a // beside Evaluate? Also, what does Thread do here? I've read the documentation but I don't really understand what it does. Where did you specify the initial conditions, is it sol[200,10^-1]?

Comment: @mathemania 1. As said above, `Evaluate` here evaluates the whole first argument i.e. `{H[t], (3/10 ρ[t] π^2)^(1/4)} /. 
   Thread[{y, ρ} -> sol[200, 10^-1]]`. 2. For example, `Thread[{a, b} -> {c, d}]` evaluates to `{a -> b, c -> d}`, that's exactly what I've done here. Actually if you feel confused about what `Thread` has done here, you can simply copy the `Thread[{y, ρ} -> sol[200, 10^-1]]` out and execute it and observe. 3. Yes, don't forget the `sol` here is a `ParametricFunction`. 4. I believe you'll find [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871) interesting.

Comment: @mathemania 5. As to the meaning of `//`, just move your cursor to the right of it (or to the middle of it, or simply select it by double click) and press F1 and read its document. Also, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871).

Comment: 1. So // is somehow the same as [ ], right? `{H[t], (3/10 ρ[t] π^2)^(1/4)} /. Thread[{y, ρ} -> sol[200, 10^-1]] // Evaluate` is equivalent to `Evaluate[{H[t], (3/10 ρ[t] π^2)^(1/4)} /. Thread[{y, ρ} -> sol[200, 10^-1]]]` 2. So `Thread` is like `Evaluate` but in a more specific way, such that if there are many things that needs to be evaluated, like a matching type of thing.

Comment: @mathemania 1. Yes. 2. No, `Thread` is a function for list manipulation, as shown in the document, it can change `f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]` to `{f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]}`. (Don't forget `Rule`(`->`) is a function i.e. it just plays the role of `f` here. BTW, you should also read those examples when reading the document. ) `Evaluate` is for adjusting evaluation order. `Evaluate` and `Thread` are totally different.

Comment: I'm really learning from your explanations. I'm in the process of learning Mathematica so pardon me for my lack of experience, however I need to get some results using Mathematica at the fastest time possible so I just need to improvise sometimes. Also, why did you remove `Manipulate` in your version of the code, I'm hoping that I can vary the initial conditions so that I can see more clearly the behavior of the solution.

Comment: @mathemania Mainly because I want to keep the code clean, and partly because I think the ranges for `a`, `b` and `tf` in your code is improper. Simply add the `Manipulate` if you like, you just need to modify the `sol[200,10^-1]` to `sol[a, b]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57873/discussion-between-mathemania-and-xzczd).